# Как установить значение по умолчанию из соседнего значения?

Tags: python

Я хочу создать функцию в которой

```
def fun(text_1=1, text_2=text_1) :
    print(text_1 + text_2)
fun()     # получится 1+1=2
fun(6)    # получится 6+6=12
fun(9, 8) # получится 9+8=17
```

Если `text_2=None` то `text_2 == text_1`
Можно ли в python такое реализовать без написания кучи `if:else:`

```
def fun(color, color_hover, back, back_hover, border, border_hover):
    if color == None:
        color="#000"
    if color_hover == None:
        color_hover=color
    if back == None:
        back="#fff"
    if back_hover == None:
        back_hover=back
    if border == None:
        border=back
    if border_hover == None:
        border_hover=border
```

Могу ли я как нибудь оптимизировать этот код?

Comment: Можно написать без кучи, а всего одним.

Comment: кучу не надо, только один

Comment: Я знаю я написал упращеный вариант но если это `fun(text_1=1, text_2=text_1, text_3=1, text_4=text_3,text_5=text_4, text_6=text_5, text_7=1, text_8=text_7)` то задолбаешься писать все `if:else:`

Comment: Да вы может неправильный вопрос задаёте. В чём исходная задача, может там надо просто обезличенный список обрабатывать, а не тучу именованных переменных.

Comment: @orlatym не задолбаешься. То, что вы пишете, в питоне вообще невозможно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Возможно. Я просто хочу упрастить код для лучьшей его оптимиаций

Answer (score 1):

В python в аргументе нельзя указать динамическое значение, зависящее от других аргументов, поскольку на этапе объявления их ещё не существует. И при попытке подобного объявления:

```
def fun(text_1=1, text_2=text_1) :
    pass
```

Вы получите ошибку о том, что `name 'text_1' is not defined`.

Но ничего не мешает эту зависимость прописать в теле самого метода:

```
def fun(text_1=1, text_2=None) :   
    text_2 = text_2 or text_1
    print(text_1 + text_2) 
fun() # получится 1+1=2 
fun(6) # получится 6+6=12 
fun(9, 8) # получится 9+8=17
```

**Update:**

Либо еще лучше так:

```
def fun(text_1=1, text_2=None) :   
    text_2 = text_1 if text_2 is None else text_2
    print(text_1 + text_2) 
fun(1) # получится 1+1=2 
fun(6) # получится 6+6=12 
fun(9, 8) # получится 9+8=17
```

Ибо, как ниже подметил **Qwertiy**, для `text_2=text_2 or text_1` не предусмотрен случай, когда вторым аргументом будет передан `0`

Comment: Только с ноликом проблемы.

Comment: @Qwertiy , верно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то может так:

```
def func(*args):
   default = [color1,..., colorN)
   for i,n in enumerate(args):
      if n == None:
         n = default[i]
```

Comment: Задумка хороша, вот только отступы бы поправить и синтаксис валидный сделать...

Comment: @Александр  какая разница между `*args` и `args=[]`?

Comment: @orlatym , https://tproger.ru/translations/python-args-and-kwargs/